# Splitting theorems in finite p-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, group-extensions

By a splitting theorem I mean a statement of the type: if $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ and some hypotheses are satisfied, then there is a complement, that is a subgroup $Q$ of $G$ such that $G = N \rtimes Q$.

Examples of this are the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, where the condition is that $|N|$ and $|G/N|$ be coprime; or the Gaschütz theorem, which reduces the splitting over an abelian $p$-group to the splitting of a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ over the same $p$-group.

In general, there always seem to be statements about prime divisors, and I cannot find any statement in the $p$-group case, where none of the above applies. Is there any general statement about splittings in finite $p$-groups? Or is there some theory that has been developed to deal with what looks like the hardest case?

I would be happy even with a statement about abelian $p$-groups.

Comment: It seems other people have struggled to find information in [similar questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347709/sufficient-condition-for-complementation-of-abelian-normal-subgroup). I'm not aware of any results myself either, so I'm not sure how much there is to say.

Comment: For abelian $p$-groups, you may want to take a look at [pure subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_subgroup). I doubt there is any general statement for (non-abelian) finite $p$-groups.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thanks for pointing this out! Do you think anything similar may work for 2-step solvable groups? So $N$ and $G/N$ as in the question are abelian?

Comment: @frafour, I don't think so. Take a non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p$, where $p > 2$ is a prime. Take $N = G'$. Then $N$ and $G/N$ are abelian, but $G$ does not split over $N$.